# Can see internal drive on other workgroup PC, but not external

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I have 2 Windows 10 PCs and want to use one as a file server. I have activated network discovery on both, with no passwords required.

I have 3 drives on the server which I want to share. All have full control read/write access for everyone.

From my laptop I can see the server and the three drives, but I can only explore the internal drive, the externals give me `you do not have permission to access ...`

---

[Update] I just realized that the drive which I can access from my laptop is internal to the server, whereas the two which I cannot access are external, connected by USB.

Comment: Not to derail your attempt at finding a diagnosis, but "All have full control read/write access for everyone." just seems patently unsafe.   Have you considered that in trying to be zero-security, you may have triggered self-defensive behavior in the machine(s) you might be using as clients?

Comment: It may not be the server that is denying access, but the client in trying to save you from doing something very unsafe.  Honestly I don't expect that kind of sensible behavior out of MS products, but I'm a bit jaded.

Comment: Well, I don't want passwords within my workgroup, so "full access for everyone". I think the telling point is that I can see the server & its 3 drives, but can only access the internal drive. What's the difference there?